# ReferenceError: botao is not defined

Tags: javascript

Queria saber qual é o erro nesse código. O botão está definido, sim, e o console apontando esse erro.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
        var botao = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
            function funcaoAuxiliar(j) {
                alert('Você clicou o botão ' + j);
            };
        }; 
    for (var i=0; i<botao.length; i++) {
        botao[i].onclick = funcaoAuxiliar(i);
    }
    </script>

        <button type="button">botao0</button>
        <button type="button">botao1</button>
        <button type="button">botao2</button>
        <button type="button">botao3</button>
        <button type="button">botao4</button>
        <button type="button">botao5</button>
```

Comment: Por quê o `for` está fora do `window.onload`? Aliás, fazer `botao[i].onclick = funcaoAuxiliar(i)` não funcionará, pois você está executando a função ao invés de atribuí-la ao evento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro que lhe aparece é porque o código de atribuição dos clicks dos botões é feito antes do `window.onload`, este:

```
for (var i=0; i<botao.length; i++) {
    botao[i].onclick = funcaoAuxiliar(i);
}
```

Porque está fora do `window.onload`, que só vai correr quando a página for totalmente carregada.

E se o `window.onload` ainda não correu então a variável `botao` nem sequer existe.

Para além disso `botao[i].onclick = funcaoAuxiliar(i);` estava a chamar a função em vez de a atribuir apenas ao `onclick`.

Para corrigir tem de passar o bloco de código para dentro do `window.onload` e 
 alterar a definição do `click` no `for`:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var botao = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

  for (let i = 0; i < botao.length; i++) { //com let i, em vez de var i
    botao[i].onclick = function() { //agora já não precisa do parametro
      alert('Você clicou o botão ' + i);
    };
  }
};
```

```html
<button type="button">botao0</button>
<button type="button">botao1</button>
<button type="button">botao2</button>
<button type="button">botao3</button>
<button type="button">botao4</button>
<button type="button">botao5</button>
```

Comment: Então toda vez que eu faço isso -> var X = function(b,h);  eu estou atribuindo a função, e sem o parâmetro, eu estou penas chamando ela ?

Comment: @Fernando `var x = function(a,b){... };` está a atribuir a função. 
`var x = nomeDaFuncaoJaFeita(a,b);` está a chamar e guardar em `x` o resultado da função.